# Table layout is wrong when stretched to text width

Tags: tables

I am trying to change the width of my table to text width but the layout is bad as shown below .. Any ideas?

[image]

My Code:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{T1}} & \textbf{T2} & \textbf{T3} \\ \hline
\textbf{M1}                 & 111                                   & 111               & 111               \\ \hline
\textbf{M2}                 & 111                                     & 111              & 111               \\ \hline
\textbf{M3}                 & 111                                     & 111               & 111            \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{My Matrix}
\label{table4}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You need to change some of the `l` column types to `X`.

Comment: At least one column specification should be `X` if using `tabularx` environment. Try `{|*{4}{X|}}`.

Comment: it gave an error, Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   |
l.269 \end{tabularx}..If there is any other idea .. I don't know except tabularx but you can help me using any other tag.

Comment: note that tabularx is designed for _paragraphs_ of text and adjusts the width for line breaking within the cells, stretching numeric tables with cell entries that can not be broken over a line should be a non aim, it is better to use `tabular`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you change three of the four column types from `l` to `X`. Since the "T1" header is centered, I would assume that you would want to center "T2" and "T3" as well.

*Addendum*: To center all contents of columns 2, 3, and 4, I would first define a "centered-X" column type (in the preamble) as follows

```
 \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

and then use the newly-defined `Y` column type for these columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}    
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|X|}
\hline
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{T1}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{T2}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{T3}} \\ \hline
\textbf{M1} & 111 & 111 & 111 \\ \hline
\textbf{M2} & 111 & 111 & 111 \\ \hline
\textbf{M3} & 111 & 111 & 111 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Table with ``X'' column types} \label{table:X}

\bigskip\bigskip

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|Y|Y|Y|}
\hline 
\textbf{M1} & 111 & 111 & 111 \\ \hline
\textbf{M2} & 111 & 111 & 111 \\ \hline
\textbf{M3} & 111 & 111 & 111 \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Table with ``Y'' column types} \label{table:Y}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @phx I have to wait 3 mins .. it doesn't enable me

Comment: @Mico can you make the numbers centralized?

Comment: @SMH Oops, sorry. I was too fast :p

Comment: @SMH - I've provided an addendum to my answer, to address your follow-up query.